# Android - new BitmapDrawable(Resources,Bitmap) creates a refference or an object?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

```
Drawable backDrawable;

Bitmap bitmap= .............
backDrawable= new BitmapDrawable(con.getResources(),bitmap);
bitmap.recycle();
```

I wanted to recycle the bitmap to save memory. but this code crashes when I used the backDrawable in later operations.It only worked when I removed the line bitmap.recycle(); Does BitmapDrawable() just create a refference instead of creating a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `BitmapDrawable` constructor that you're using:

```
public BitmapDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
    this(new BitmapState(bitmap), res);
    mBitmapState.mTargetDensity = mTargetDensity;
}
```

It initializes a new `BitmapState` internally with your given `Bitmap`. Looking at `BitmapState`'s constructor:

```
BitmapState(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

It directly references the Bitmap that you give it. Which makes sense, as it would be pretty terrible from a memory standpoint to copy a bitmap every time you want to wrap it into a `Drawable`.

Comment: so I don't have to worry about extra memory being used by creating the drawable. thank you for your quick response

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, the drawable won't use an additional bitmap, so you should be good. Also, if this bitmap is just from a resource, you're actually better off using `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image)` and letting the system handle proper caching for you.